# Getting output from JQGrid in xmlstring form

Tags: jqgrid

I don't know if this is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I know that you can load xmlstring data into jqgrid: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_string

but I am looking to give the user the ability to then add/remove rows.  I then want to output that string.  How would I do that?

Do I have to iterate through all the rows and build it myself? or is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to iterate over the grid.  You can use [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to extract data for each row add it to an XML string / document.